# Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(AddTodo)".when executing npm test

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

https://github.com/RitikPatni/react-todo

When running "npm test" I get the following:

Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(AddTodo)". Either wrap the root component in a , or pass a custom React context provider to  and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(AddTodo) in connect options.

I am pretty sure it comes from the line inside components/addTodo.js:

```
export default connect()(AddTodo);
```

But I am not sure what I should modify in order for the test to run successfully without breaking the application.

This is the test that fails and it's inside App.test.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

it('renders without crashing', () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, div);
  ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
});
```

After reading Drew Reese's excellent answer I tried this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import todo from './reducers/todo'

it('renders without crashing', () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={createStore(todo, [{
      id: 1,
      dueDate: new Date('July 22, 2018 07:22:13').toDateString(),
      completed: false,
      text: 'Run the tests',
      deleted: false,
  }])}>
      <App />
    </Provider>,
    div
  );
  ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
});
```

However, I am getting:

```
 FAIL  src/App.test.js
  ● Console

    console.log src/reducers/todo.js:2
      { type: '@@redux/INIT1.z.e.5.x' }
    console.error node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:530
      Warning: Invalid DOM property `class`. Did you mean `className`?
          in span (at addTodo.js:38)
          in form (at addTodo.js:10)
          in div (at addTodo.js:9)
          in AddTodo (created by Context.Consumer)
          in Connect(AddTodo) (at App.js:7)
          in div (at App.js:5)
          in App (at App.test.js:18)
          in Provider (at App.test.js:11)
    console.error node_modules/prop-types/checkPropTypes.js:20
      Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `todos` is marked as required in `TodoList`, but its value is `undefined`.
          in TodoList (created by Context.Consumer)
          in Connect(TodoList) (at App.js:8)
          in div (at App.js:5)
          in App (at App.test.js:18)
          in Provider (at App.test.js:11)
    console.error node_modules/prop-types/checkPropTypes.js:20
      Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `toggleTodo` is marked as required in `TodoList`, but its value is `undefined`.
          in TodoList (created by Context.Consumer)
          in Connect(TodoList) (at App.js:8)
          in div (at App.js:5)
          in App (at App.test.js:18)
          in Provider (at App.test.js:11)
    console.error node_modules/prop-types/checkPropTypes.js:20
      Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `removeTodo` is marked as required in `TodoList`, but its value is `undefined`.
          in TodoList (created by Context.Consumer)
          in Connect(TodoList) (at App.js:8)
          in div (at App.js:5)
          in App (at App.test.js:18)
          in Provider (at App.test.js:11)
    console.error node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21843
      The above error occurred in the <Context.Consumer> component:
          in Connect(TodoList) (at App.js:8)
          in div (at App.js:5)
          in App (at App.test.js:18)
          in Provider (at App.test.js:11)

      Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
      Visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html to learn more about error boundaries.

  ● renders without crashing

    Unknown filter: undefined

       8 |       return todos;
       9 |     default:
    > 10 |       throw new Error('Unknown filter: ' + filter);
         |             ^
      11 |   }
      12 | };
      13 | 

      at getVisibleTodos (src/components/visibleTodoList.js:10:13)
      at Function.mapStateToProps [as mapToProps] (src/components/visibleTodoList.js:16:12)
      at mapToPropsProxy (node_modules/react-redux/lib/connect/wrapMapToProps.js:53:92)
      at Function.detectFactoryAndVerify (node_modules/react-redux/lib/connect/wrapMapToProps.js:62:19)
      at mapToPropsProxy (node_modules/react-redux/lib/connect/wrapMapToProps.js:53:46)
      at handleFirstCall (node_modules/react-redux/lib/connect/selectorFactory.js:34:18)
      at pureFinalPropsSelector (node_modules/react-redux/lib/connect/selectorFactory.js:75:81)
      at Connect.selectDerivedProps (node_modules/react-redux/lib/components/connectAdvanced.js:126:25)
      at Connect.renderWrappedComponent (node_modules/react-redux/lib/components/connectAdvanced.js:183:33)
      at Connect.indirectRenderWrappedComponent (node_modules/react-redux/lib/components/connectAdvanced.js:168:21)
      at updateContextConsumer (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:19844:19)
      at beginWork$1 (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:20227:14)
      at beginWork$$1 (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:25756:14)
      at performUnitOfWork (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24698:12)
      at workLoopSync (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24671:22)
      at performSyncWorkOnRoot (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24270:11)
      at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:23698:7)
      at updateContainer (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:27103:3)
      at node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:27528:7
      at unbatchedUpdates (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24433:12)
      at legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:27527:5)
      at Object.render (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:27608:10)
      at Object.<anonymous>.it (src/App.test.js:10:12)
```

Tried:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import todo from './reducers/todo'
import rootReducer from './reducers/';

const store = createStore(rootReducer);


it('renders without crashing', () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>,
    div
  );
  ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
});
```

And now the test passes. Not sure if it's ok to pass the rootReducer store though.

Comment: The usual pattern is to also export the "unconnected" component for testing and manually pass the props (mapped from state) the connect HOC provides, this way you won't have to mock up a redux store provider or create a wrapper for testing.

Comment: You mean export addTodo after App, but how do you pass the props? Also, what's a HOC? Also, isn't it better to create a wrapper? Although, I have no idea what kind of wrapper is expected.

Comment: HOC == higher order component. Does your `AddTodo` actually use anything from the `connect` HOC? i.e. Do you actually map any state or dispatch actions to props? If not then try removing the `connect` wrapper from the export. **EDIT** NM, I see you simply use the connected `dispatch` prop internally.

Comment: I actually just pulled some repo I found on Github to unit test it, so I am unfamiliar with the application. The confusing part is that there's no mapDispatchToProps, and the dispatch is given as an arg to the component. I am assuming it's using some sort of middleware to do the necessary wiring. As for the HOC, I am guessing it's the App.js component.

Comment: `connect` **is** a HOC provided by react-redux. It also injects a dispatch callback but normally you'd use `mapDispatchToProps` to wrap actions in a call to dispatch so you can simply call the action within the component.

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks. I just noticed that connect() is wrapping the component AddTodo, I didn't know connect() was a component too, I thought it was just an ordinary middleware function and not a functional component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual pattern is to also export the "unconnected" component for testing and manually pass the props (mapped from state) the connect [HOC (Higer Order Component)](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) provides, this way you won't have to mock up a redux store provider or create a wrapper for testing.

```
export const MyComponent = ({ myProp }) => {
  return (<div>{myProp}</div>);
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ myProp: state.someStateValue });

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent);
```

testing MyComponent

```
// all the other testing imports
import { MyComponent } from './MyComponent'; // notice using named unconnected component, not the default export

it('renders without crashing', () => {
  // Something like this
  // render(<MyComponent myProp={ /* some value for testing */} />);
});
```

In some cases if you are testing a component that renders a connected component then you'll need to provide a wrapper that provides the context to the component needing it.

In your app test you need to render with a wrapper that provides a store:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux;
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

it('renders without crashing', () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={createStore(reducer, initialState)}>
      <App />
    </Provider>,
    div
  );
  ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
});
```

Comment: sorry for offtop, but it's not best approach anymore. With hooks in mind we better provide real or mocked store instead, otherwise we would need to rewrite our tests if refactore component from `connect()`ed version to functional with hooks

Comment: @skyboyer pattern works for class-based and functional react components, hooks are irrelevant as they are an internal implementation. It works by decoupling a store from the UI component for testing. We use both class-based and functional components in our code base and this pattern works exceptionally. (We use react-testing-library to further separate testing concerns from component implementation details).

Comment: if I pass mapStateToProps to connect(), which is currently empty, won't it impact the behavior of the application? I am wondering if I need to make a new class called addTodoWithProps and use it for the test, which would be kinda bothersome.

Comment: Unlikely, it is only mapping something from state to a prop passed to the component. It's currently empty and `AddTodo` has no other props (than `dispatch`) so would have no effect. In my above example the raw component has a prop, `myProp` that can be passed via the `connect` HOC (when wrapped), or directly, as is the case in the test.

Comment: so you guys don't use `useSelector`/`useDispatch`, do you?

Comment: Hmm, I tried your suggestion, but I am getting an error still. Not sure if I did something wrong on my end. I edited the question.

Comment: @skyboyer Unfortunately no, not at the current moment. Some member(s) of our team a good while back made some poor design decisions that locked us into an older version of `react-redux`. Overall though, I do prefer not having my presentational UI components coupled tightly to my state, but instead prefer the use of the container pattern to handle the logic of mapping a data source to the UI.

Comment: @hero looks like you may need to mock some more up in the provider. `visibleTodoList` looks like it is also connected and passes a bunch of "connect" props to `TodoList` that appear to be missing. (IMHO) This is the trouble of testing connected components, you just have to keep mocking the missing bits until it runs.

Comment: It does run with the rootReducer store though. Check the updated question. Now, I am wondering if this is alright or I may need to do some other stuffs in the future for some other tests.

Comment: In my test suite I pass our root reducer (and empty `{}` initial state) to my redux wrapper/provider, this way anything I render that needs redux will receive what it needs with the default state the reducers create.